# Query Timeout in "MySQL for Excel"

Tags: mysql, excel

Is there a way to set the query timeout in "MySQL for Excel"? I have a couple of MySQL stored procedures that run fine from MySQL Workbench (slow, but fine), but are failing when called from Excel with "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."  Optimizing and/or indexing to speed up the SP is not an option... I already did all that I can, short of creating a datawarehouse.  I did try putting "SET SESSION wait_timeout = 300;" at the top of the procedure in question... no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153756

Comment: The query times out in 30 seconds.  I scanned the registry for anything like 'timeout'... there were a number of 'QUERYTIMEOUT' entries, but they all had a value of 60.  I tried changing the Jet related entries to 300, with no effect.  If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.  Thanks!